# Manipulating/splicing List of Lists

Tags: python, list, range, shapes, tolist

Good evening,
    May I please get advice for the following code? Here is what I have:

```
z_list = df.iloc[0:5000,2]   
n = 1000 #chunk row size
list_df = [z_list[i:i+n].tolist() for i in range(0,z_list.shape[0],n)]
```

This section of Python code generates a list of lists, 5 lists of 1000 rows each. This will be used later for another script. However, I would like to take "list_df" and cut down the size of each list from 1000 to a fraction of that (instead of 1000, I may want the first 300 rows of each list instead, so 5 lists of 300 rows). Most solutions I've tried don't seem to apply to this list-of-lists setup, so I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list slicing?

```
shortened_sublists = [sublist[:300] for sublist in list_df]
```

Comment: Thank you good sir, that worked! That's exactly what I needed.